# Function to parse an XML and find specific regex considering the size attribute of the document

Tags: python, xml

I'm writing a code that, starting from an XML file:

- stores the index of child elements of a tag and the child elements as
  key, values in a dictionary (function `get_xml_by_tag_names`);
- deletes keys whose values contain a certain string (the specific text
  size) and puts these keys and the corresponding values into a second
  dictionary (`def search_delete_append`);
- joins, for each dictionary, the dict values and extracts their
  text(`def main`);
- replaces certain values with "" (`def main`);
- counts the occurrences of specific regex I specify (`def find_regex`).

It works, but the "main" function needs to be more cleaned up. My concerns specifically regard the part in which I have to list the regex I'm interested in- they're multiple and it can become messy. Another problem is that the cleaning of the XML can be done in another separate function, but so I haven't managed to do it.

Here is the code:

```
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path, tag_name_1, tag_name_2):

    data = {}
    xml_tree = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_group_nodes = xml_tree.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_1)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_2)
        for _ in cl_compile_nodes:
            data[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
    return data


def find_regex(regex, text):
    l = []
    matches_prima = re.findall(regex, text)
    print("The number of", {regex}," matches is ", len(matches_prima))



def search_delete_append(dizionario, dizionariofasi):
    deletekeys = []
    insertvalues = []
    for k in dizionario:
        for v in dizionario[k]:
            if "7.489" in v:
                deletekeys.append(k)
                dizionariofasi[k] = v

    for item in deletekeys:
        del dizionario[item]


def main():
    dict_fasi = {}
    data = get_xml_by_tag_names('output2.xml', 'new_line', 'text')
    search_delete_append(data, dict_fasi)

    testo = []
    for value in data.values():
        myxml = ' '.join(value)
        tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
        tmpstring = ' '.join(text.text for text in tree.findall('text'))
        for to_remove in (" < ", " >", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>"):
            tmpstring = tmpstring.replace(to_remove, "")
        testo.append(tmpstring)
    testo = ''.join(testo)
    #print(testo)
    find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
    #print(find_regex(find_prima, testo))
    #################

    testo_fasi = []
    values = [x for x in dict_fasi.values()]
    myxml_fasi = ' '.join(values)
    find_CM = re.compile(r"10\.238")
    print(find_regex(find_CM, myxml_fasi)) #quanti CM ci sono?
    #print(myxml_fasi)
    for x in dict_fasi.values():
        xxx= ''.join(x)
        tree2 = ET.fromstring(xxx)
        tmpstring2 = ' '.join(text.text for text in tree2.findall('text'))
        testo_fasi.append(tmpstring2)
    testo_fasi = ''.join(testo_fasi)
    print(testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_prima, testo_fasi)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Per https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-code-be-forcibly-translated-into-english it is preferable if your code is shown in English rather than Italian. I think your code is still on-topic; it would just clarify your code for your reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

### Mixed languages

Regardless of one's opinion on whether English is the *lingua franca* of programming, mixing languages is a bad idea. This would be better in all-Italian (where possible; libraries are still in English) or all-English than a mixture.

### Type hints

Use them; for instance

```
def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path: str, tag_name_1: str, tag_name_2: str) -> dict:
```

### Unused variable

Here:

```
l = []
```

### Items iteration

```
for k in dizionario:
    for v in dizionario[k]:
```

should be

```
for k, values in dizionario.items():
    for v in values:
```

### Magic numbers

Move this:

```
"7.489"
```

to a named constant variable somewhere.

### Multiple replacement

This:

```
    for to_remove in (" < ", " >", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>"):
```

would be easier as a single regular expression and a single call to `sub`.

### Intermediate list

```
values = [x for x in dict_fasi.values()]
myxml_fasi = ' '.join(values)
```

can just be

```
myxml_fasi = ' '.join(dict_fasi.values())
```